# Why my script ignoring empty array result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script that basically check if there is a result from a query:

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('xxx/yyy'); ?>',{data:no},function(result){
        if(!result){
            alert("No Data");
        }
        else{
            alert("Data retrieved");
        }
});
```

Why my `IF` alert `Data retrieved` when I get empty JSON array. I tried to do `alert(result)` with different data (the data which result is empty and result is true), but both data is alerting `Data retrieved`.

This is my model:

```
$this->db->select('*',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('t_penomoran tp');      
    $this->db->join('t_penomoran_detail t_pd', 'tp.nomor = t_pd.nomor');

    $this->db->where('tp.nomor',$nomor);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

**note:**
For some reason when I do `alert(result.length)` with data that has no value, the result is `2`. But when I do `alert(result)` with data that has no value the result is `[]`

Comment: Empty JSON array [] in stringified form is still string, so maybe you need to parse the result to actual JSON first?

Comment: @DanielH.J. _"[JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](http://json.org) is a lightweight data-interchange format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Andreas, what I am saying is the Ajax result is an empty JSON array that is stringified, so [] is not the same as '[]'. '[]' is a string with length of 2. You need to parse the result first.

Comment: @DanielH.J. If the server doesn't send `application/json` as the content-type you're right. Otherwise jQuery will automatically parse the response (https://jsfiddle.net/Lpt9n8q3/).

Answer (score 1):

Empty array is a `truthy` value, meaning in your `if` statement, it will evaluate to `true` and that is why you see the `alert()`. To fix it, use the `length` property:

```
if(!result.length) alert('no data')
```

Comment: still no luck. For some reason when I do `alert(result.length)` with data that has no value, the result is 2. But when I do `alert(result)` with data that has no value the result is `[]`

Comment: That correlates to result being a string of length 2, namely`”[]”`

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
 if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(result))
{
        alert('no data')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all parse your result like this

```
var res = result.responseJSON;
```

Then alert what you get if empty then it will be null. so you can filter that out